# CORS and EXPRESS - [Error] Origin http://<ip address>:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io, cors

I try to implement backend and frontend Application but it always has an error even I use cors.

Please help to verify the code below:

Backend server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);
const cors = require('cors');

const ds18b20 = require('ds18b20');

const port = 4001;
const getTemperature = require('./utils/temperature');

let interval;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  if(interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  var sensorId = [];
  ds18b20.sensors((err, id) => {
    sensorId = id;
    socket.emit('sensors', id);
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    sensorId.forEach((id) => {
      ds18b20.temperature(id, (err, value) => {
        console.log(value);
        socket.emit('FromAPI', {'id': id, 'value': value});
      });
    });
  }, interval);

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hi');
});
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

frontend App.js from create-react-app

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
// import { Button, Input } from 'react-bootstrap';

const ENDPOINT = "http://172.20.10.5:4001";
const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
      setResponse(data);
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <p>
      Temp is {response.value} degree celsius
    </p>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Error shown below:

> [Error] Origin http://172.20.10.5:3000 is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin. [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> http://172.20.10.5:4001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOu0oIM
> due to access control checks. [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin
> http://172.20.10.5:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> (socket.io, line 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cors` option. Refer to [Handling CORS](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/).

```
const io = socketIO(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*"
  }
})
```